# Terror message TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'module'

Tags: python

```
""" Random module that defines a series of functions
      for generating or manipulating random integers
"""
import random


""" Function to display the title and programming
      specifications of the project
"""
def display_title(name, specifications):
  print(name+""+specifications)

display_title('The game is called Guessing game\n',
                         'The rules are simple Pick a number  between 1 and 10\n')

""" Function that uses the randint() function that gets the number
      the player has to guess and then returns a random number
      between 1 and 10
"""
def play_game():
  random=random.randint(1,10)

"""While statement so the user can guess the number until the
     the guess is correct
"""
while True:
  guess=int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10   '))
  
  
  if guess < random:
      print('Too low')

  elif guess > random:
      print('Too high')

  else:
        print('You guessed it')
```

I tried changing the spacing but I do not think the error is a result of spacing.
I would like the code to run without error

Comment: random is a module and also a variable, I'm sorry your compiler got confused :) as in you imported random and also declared a variable named random that is equal to a randint(1,10). But you never called play_game(). Just name it something different thats all and put the while loop inside the play_game function

Comment: you never call `play_game()` so the `random` variable is never assigned an integer, so the name `random` still refers to the module. In general, you shouldn't be naming variables such that they override modules.

Comment: `random=random.randint(1,10)` This assignment occurs as a local variable inside the `play_game()` function, and it is not visible anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the same name for a variable and a module.  You're just asking for confusion, as you've seen.  In this case, you're importing `random`, and also using it as a local variable name:

```
def play_game():
  random=random.randint(1,10)
```

The assignment to `random` makes it a local variable, which locally overrides the `random` module.  So when it tries to evaluate `random.randint(1,10)`, it's using the undefined variable `random`, which of course gives an error.  So use a different name, e.g.:

```
def play_game():
  rand_val=random.randint(1,10)
```

This will solve part of the problem.  But the other problem is that, even with this fix, `rand_val` is still local to `play_game`, and cannot be accessed outside of it.  It would be better to have `play_game` return the value, but if you really want to use a global for it, then you need to declare it global, e.g.:

```
def play_game():
  global rand_val
  rand_val=random.randint(1,10)
```

If you do this, then you can access `rand_val` from other functions (once `play_game` has been called).

And of course, you need to actually call `play_game()`, which you aren't currently doing.

Here's a complete solution.  I didn't include the title code since it has nothing to do with the problem:

```
import random


def play_game():
    global rand_val
    rand_val=random.randint(1,10)


play_game()

while True:
    guess=int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10   '))

    if guess < rand_val:
        print('Too low')

    elif guess > rand_val:
        print('Too high')

    else:
        print('You guessed it')
        break
```

This works.  Once the number is guessed, it exits the loop.

By the way, it would probably make more sense to have the `play_game` function actually play the game, i.e. move the game loop there.  That would also let you eliminate the global variable (it could be local).

Comment: I recieved thfollowing error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'function'
def play_game():
  global rand_val
  rand_val=random.randint(1,10)   
        
  
"""While statement so the user can guess the number until the
     the guess is correct
"""
while True:
  guess=int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 10   '))
  
  
  if guess < play_game:
      print('Too low')

  elif guess > play_game:
      print('Too high')

  else:
        print('You guessed it')

Comment: If you made the changes I described, you would not be getting that error.  I just tried it and there are no errors.  (1) Change your `random` variable to `rand_val` *everywhere it's referenced* (2) declare it global inside `play_game` (3) call `play_game()` before trying to access `rand_val` in your main code.  It works.  You must have done something different.

Comment: Ok, I just updated my answer to include a complete example (minus the title stuff, which had nothing to do with the problem).  It works, and it's exactly what I described.  See if you can find what you did different.

Comment: I entered the wrong spacing for (3) call play_game ()   thankssssssss

Comment: Note that it would probably make more sense to move the game loop into the `play_game` function, so that it actually plays the game as the name implies (I added a comment to the answer mentioning this), but at least the problem you posted about should be solved now.

Comment: Note that it would probably make more sense to move the game loop into the `play_game` function, so that it actually plays the game as the name implies (I added a comment to the answer mentioning this), but at least the problem you posted about should be solved now.  If so, you can "accept" the answer.